# Query to Return each product name with its amount due, paid, cancelled, and refunded

Tags: mysql

Three table are given to get the product details such as *product_name*, *due_amount*,*paid_amount*,*cancelled*,*refunded*. Three table with their schema:

**Product**

| Column_name | Column_type | Key/NULL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | pk |
| SKU | varchar(32) |  |
| product_name | varchar(128) |  |
| product_desc | text |  |
| current_price | decimal(8,2) |  |
| qty_in_stock | int |  |

**Invoice**

| Column_name | Column_type | Key/NULL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | pk |
| invoice_number | int |  |
| customer_id | int |  |
| user_account_id | int |  |
| total_price | decimal(8,2) |  |
| time_issued | varchar | N |
| time_due | varchar | N |
| time_paid | varchar | N |
| time_cancelled | varchar | N |
| time_refunded | varchar | N |

**Invoice_item**

| Column_name | Column_type | Key/NULL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | pk |
| invoice_id | int | fk |
| product_id | int | fk |
| quantity | int | fk |
| price | decimal(8,2) |  |
| line_total_price | decimal(8,2) |  |

I tried in this way:

```
SELECT Distinct product, amount_due,amount_paid,cancelled_prod,refund_prod
    FROM   (SELECT p.product_name AS product,
                    ((p.current_price * ii.quantity) - (ii.quantity * ii.price)) AS amount_due,
                    ( ii.quantity * ii.price )  AS amount_paid,
                    'N/A' AS Cancelled_prod,
                    'N/A' AS refund_prod
            FROM   product p
            INNER JOIN invoice_item ii
            ON p.id = ii.product_id
            INNER JOIN invoice i
            ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
            WHERE  i.time_due IS NOT NULL

            UNION

            SELECT p.product_name AS product,
                    0 AS amount_due,
                    ( ii.quantity * ii.price ) AS amount_paid,
                   'N/A' AS Cancelled_prod,
                   'N/A' AS refund_prod
            FROM   product p
            INNER JOIN invoice_item ii
            ON p.id = ii.product_id
            INNER JOIN invoice i
            ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
            WHERE  i.time_paid IS NOT NULL

            UNION

            SELECT p.product_name AS product,
                    0 AS amount_due,
                    0 AS amount_paid,
                    'cancelled' AS Cancelled_prod,
                    'N/A' AS refund_prod
            FROM   product p
            INNER JOIN invoice_item ii
            ON p.id = ii.product_id
            INNER JOIN invoice i
            ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
            WHERE  i.time_cancelled IS NOT NULL

            UNION

            SELECT p.product_name AS product,
                    0 AS amount_due,
                    0 AS amount_paid,
                    'N/A' AS Cancelled_prod,
                    'refunded' AS refund_prod
            FROM   product p
            INNER JOIN invoice_item ii
            ON p.id = ii.product_id
            INNER JOIN invoice i
            ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
            WHERE  i.time_refunded IS NOT NULL
        ) Z
    ORDER  BY product ASC



Is there a better way to do and also i am not sure whether the query will give correct result?
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't run as far as I can tell. When using union all parts must return the same number of columns and have the same datatype. Your first query has 5 columns, your second 3, your third has 4 and the final query has 5 again. As for giving the correct results, I would guess not because I think invoices will be duplicated (e.g. if time due is not null and time paid is not null the same invoice will appear twice). With that being said, the person in the best position to say if the results are correct is you, because you know what you actually want!

Comment: @GarethD I have made some changes to get only distinct products and have added all missing variables. Please look into it once more.

Comment: We'd need to understand more about your data, and what results you want to make a suggestion. For example, is it possible for `time_paid` to be populated as well as `time_refunded` (I'd expect so since it shouldn't be possible to refund someone who has not paid). In this case would you expect the data to appear twice, once as "Paid", and once as refunded (which is what your current query does), or would you expect a single record for each product showing as refunded? I think as well as the table structure we need sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 3):

```
select product_name, sum(amount_due), sum(amount_paid), sum(amount_cancelled), sum(amount_refunded) 
from (
select product_name,
case when time_due is not null then line_total_price end amount_due,
case when time_paid is not null then line_total_price end amount_paid,
case when time_cancelled is not null then line_total_price end amount_cancelled,
case when time_refunded is not null then line_total_price end amount_refunded
from product a left join invoice_item c on a.id = c.product_id
left join invoice b on b.id = c.invoice_id 
) temp_table 
group by product_name order by product_name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).